# How to display content of several text files on the terminal with shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I've got two text files :

line1.txt :

> 1 2 3 4

line2.txt :

> 5 6 7 8

With shell, I want to display the content of these two files on the terminal like this :

> 1 2 3 4
>
> 5 6 7 8

With which tools could I achieve this ? (I've just started to learn shell)
Thank's for your answers.

Comment: `cat` is the tool: `cat line1.txt line2.txt`

Comment: Thank's, i'll try this !